# How can I automate data frame manipulation, subbing in whatever team name input I have to return the manipulated version of that data? R

Tags: r, function, dplyr, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

My goal is to use some sort of automated process where I can input a team name for team across all occurances in a chunk of code. I have been trying tom ake a function to do so. I have provided a subset of manipulations I would like to make, the manual coding that would do the same action, and a function with "team" in place of the example team name "falcons"

Tidied, manual version:

```
library(dplyr)

falconscap2022 <- falconscap2022 |>
  mutate(cash = sum(average),
         nump = n(), 
         .by = posg) |>
  mutate(cap_pct = percent(cash/sum(cash)))

falconspicks2022 <- mutate(falconspicks2022, top100 = as.numeric(pick) <= 100, .keep = "unused")

falcons2022stuff <- falconscap2022 %>%
  left_join(falconspicks2022, by = "posg")
```

Data:

```
falconscap2022 <- structure(list(average = c(18333333, 16823333, 9375000, 8227624, 
5500000, 5383617, 5250000, 4850000, 3681822, 3576437), posg = c("OL", 
"Front7", "QB", "TE", "DB", "WR", "RB", "ST", "OL", "DB")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

falconspicks2022 <- structure(list(pick = c("10", "109", "200", "94", "109"), posg = c("OL", 
"Front7", "DB", "WR", "DB")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Untidied, function version:

```
datacleanup <- function(team){
  
  
##each team will have their own precleaned data assigned, example of falcons would be falconscap2022
teamcap2022$average <- gsub(",", "",  teamcap2022$average) 
teamcap2022$average <- gsub("\\$", "",  teamcap2022$average)
teamcap2022$average <- as.numeric(teamcap2022$average)


teamcap2022 <- teamcap2022 %>%
  group_by(posg) %>%
  mutate(cash = sum(average),
            nump = n()) 

teamcap2022 <- teamcap2022 %>%
   ungroup() %>%
  mutate(cap_pct = percent(cash/sum(cash)))

##each team will also have their own precleaned picks df, example is falconspicks2022
teampicks2022 <- teampicks2022 %>%
  mutate(
    top100 = case_when(
      pick < 101 ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ 0
    ),
    latepicks = case_when( 
      pick > 100 ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ 0
      )
  ) %>% select(c("top100", "latepicks", "posg"))


team2022stuff <- teamcap2022 %>%
  left_join(teampicks2022, by = "posg")
  
  
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like datacleanup(falcons) to get the same output as the manual code

Comment: Hi Jake, welcome to Stack O! I was wondering, do you have a dataframe for each team? Or is there one for all. And if not, why not

Comment: I tidied your manual version, to make it not so verbose. There was a bunch of things in there which were totally unnecessary (e.g., using case_when when you have only two conditions, but also when the things you want are just a true or false (or 1 or 0) then you can just use an equality check, like in the code. You don't need it across many columns either.

Comment: Also kindly consider not keeping your pick numbers as strings

Comment: what you're asking to do is very simple and straightforward with one dataframe. With 32 different dataframes, it becomes a bit more unusual. I also don't know if having 32 different dataframes for what is essentially the same data type is the best of ideas

Comment: If you want to perform the same kinds of analysis / processing / visualization on 32 different data frames, they should either be in one dataframe or one list.

Comment: How does this differ from your first question?

Comment: also, I didn't explicitly point this out before, but you don't need a late picks column, if every row which isn't in the top 100 is a late pick, it can (and should) be just one column. And even if there were multiple categories (top 20, 20-100), 100-200 etc.), that can be a factor

Comment: @Mark I am scraping data for the cap information which becomes the dataframe (team name)cap2022, and filtering another dataframe from Kaggle that has all the draft information for each team (team name)picks2022. I am then splitting this into a variety of values to determine assets used for each position from picks to average yearly salary, I will then simplify this to one row and eventually add each team row to a dataframe, so I then can do an analysis to see where and how the most successful teams invest their assets.

Comment: @Jake that makes sense, but like Jon has said, use a single dataframe or a list of dataframes, if not for my happiness, then for your own sanity down the road

Comment: @Mark Also, it doesn't seem you understand what exactly I am trying to do because the full code is not provided here and missing the context of NFL roster building, I am not attempting to classify as top 100 pick or not top 100 pick, I am counting total assets used on a position, this can include average yearly salary, top 100 picks, later than top 100 picks, and much more. It is not a classifier on whether or not it is a certain pick type, but the amount of picks spent on a position. If you want more information and the precleaned data and cleaned data I would be happy to provide it.

Comment: @limey I made it more reproducible and reduced the coding like you had commented on my initial post. It of course is the same question, but with a coding example that could make it more reproducible.

Comment: @JonSpring I am scraping for 32 teams, and combining draft data with 32 teams, Each data frame is quite ugly and difficult to combine keeping the teams and their information separate but if you have suggestions on how I could do this that would be fantastic.

Comment: @Jake it might be worth creating a new question, and putting your scraping code into that... you could update this question but it feels like a separate question

Comment: it's difficult to give advice without seeing the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datacleanup2 <- function(df, df2) {
  df |>
    mutate(average = stringr::str_remove_all(average, ",|\\$") |>
             as.numeric()) |>
    mutate(cash = sum(average),
           nump = n(), .by= posg) |>
    mutate(cap_pct = scales::percent(cash/sum(cash))) |>
    left_join(df2 |>
                mutate(top100 = as.numeric(pick < 101),
                       latepicks = as.numeric(pick > 100)) |>
                select(posg, top100, latepicks))
}

datacleanup2(falconscap2022, falconspicks2022)
```

Result

```
Joining with `by = join_by(posg)`
    average   posg     cash nump cap_pct top100 latepicks
1  18333333     OL 22015155    2  19.64%      1         0
2  16823333 Front7 16823333    1  15.01%      0         1
3   9375000     QB  9375000    1   8.36%     NA        NA
4   8227624     TE  8227624    1   7.34%     NA        NA
5   5500000     DB  9076437    2   8.10%      0         1
6   5500000     DB  9076437    2   8.10%      0         1
7   5383617     WR  5383617    1   4.80%      0         1
8   5250000     RB  5250000    1   4.68%     NA        NA
9   4850000     ST  4850000    1   4.33%     NA        NA
10  3681822     OL 22015155    2  19.64%      1         0
11  3576437     DB  9076437    2   8.10%      0         1
12  3576437     DB  9076437    2   8.10%      0         1
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it, I'll attempt to apply this to the rest of the data manipulations I have

Comment: @Jake also don't forget to mark the question answered, if you found Jon's answer helpful! :-) It's another way of saying thank you